# How to recompile GHDL source code

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

Please give me the steps how to recompile the GHDL source code after specific file edited in the source code?
Thanks in advance.
Regards 
Raghu

Comment: Why did you tag this linux-kernel?  AFAIK GHDL is a compiler for the VHDL hardware description language.  Your first resource should be the project documentation.  Though if you are on linux and your distro offers a GHDL package, you can probably use the package manager to download source and build and install it in a standard way, before or after your changes.

Answer (score 1):

[Get the sources](http://ghdl.free.fr/site/pmwiki.php?n=Main.Download): `svn co svn://svn.gna.org/svn/ghdl/trunk ghdl`

Read the [README](http://svn.gna.org/svn/ghdl/trunk/README), follow the instructions.

Come back with specific questions as they arise

Comment: link is down. Is the source still available?